# Is it possible to use cloth sewing springs to make pants?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I saw a few tutorials on YouTube utilizing the cloth sewing spring method and I'm trying do such a thing with pants.

[image]
 All of the examples that I saw, have a piece of cloth going over the character's shoulder.

[image]
 Pants however don't  do so unless if they're overalls. I want to know does this method work only if a mesh is over an area of the character?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible to create pants using sewing springs. You can either turn off gravity, or pin the top of the pants to the avatar to prevent it from falling.

Comment: Please expand your answer to include information as to *how* you can turn off gravity or pin cloth.